Adding different capabilities to a Distribution profile for visionOS and iOS app
I have an app that runs on both iOS and visionOS (native). Both app use the same project, just some files and code segments are different. We do not use automatic signing. Instead we use a Distribution profile. When creating a distribution profile and adding capabilities there are certain capabilities we are using on iOS that are not available on visionOS. Like the com.apple.developer.kernel.increased-memory-limit and the Extended Virtual Addressing Entitlement. My understanding is that we can only have one Distribution profile per app (may be wrong understanding). My question is how can we have two separate distribution profiles for iOS and visionOS, so iOS can have those extra capabilities that aren't available on visionOS?
I tried to create two separate targets, one for iOS and one for visionOS, but that still gives me the same issue of having the distribution profile being the same and not being able to make it unique for iOS and visionOS. Is there a correct approach to setting up the Xcode project or the distribution profile?
I'm new to visionOS development and distribution profiles, any guidance would be appreciated. Let me know if you have any questions or need more clarification.

It sounds like you will need to publish two different apps. In exclusively for iOS and one exclusively for visionOS and then you can sign them differently as they will have different bundle IDs.

@Paulw11 That's what I'm thinking, but doesn't that kind of defy the whole point of one app supporting multiple platforms? And is there a chance Apple rejects the same due to similar binary's? I feel like I'm not approaching this correctly?

You can make your iOS apps available for vision iOS but if you are publishing a specific visionOS app then you already don't have one app running on separate platforms; you have two apps that you are hoping can share a bundle id; but this means they have to share a provisionin profile, which they can't.  I can't say what apple will or won't approve but I would have thought apps for different stores should be fine
